# How to deal with JSON response?

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following code:

```
console.info(JSON.parse(ajaxResponse.responseText));
```

Which gives me the following results:

```
{"success":[{"message":"Data Saved"}]}
```

As far as I can tell, this is just plainly a string. What do I need to do differently to be able to something along the lines of

```
console.info(ajaxResponse.message);
```

or even

```
console.info(ajaxResponse["message"]);
```

Edit: Raw unparsed response give me this plus a whole lot more stuff:

```
readyState 4
responseText ""{\"success\":[{\"message\":\"Data Saved\"}]}""
status 200
statusText "OK"
```

Comment: "*As far as I can tell, this is just plainly a string*" Either you are wrong, and it's an object, *or* the service is returning a JSON-encoded string, which you unwrap into a regular string.

Comment: Can you show `ajaxResponse.responseText`?

Comment: Edited in. You now have the first four objects in the unparsed response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON.parse(ajaxResponse.responseText) is returning a string, so you'll need to do it twice.

You can get it by parsing the responseText as JSON and then accessing it accordingly.

```
JSON.parse(JSON.parse(ajaxResponse.responseText)).success[0].message
```

Potentially (depending on what you're using to make the AJAX call) the response has a property called "responseJSON", in which case you can just do.

```
JSON.parse(ajaxResponse.responseJSON).success[0].message
```

Comment: In both cases, I get the following error: JSON.parse(...).success is undefined

Comment: what is `typeof JSON.parse(ajaxResponse.responseText)`?

Comment: console.info(typeof JSON.parse(ajaxResponse.responseText)); prints string to the console

Comment: how about `typeof JSON.parse(JSON.parse(ajaxResponse.responseText))`?

Comment: This time it tells me it's an object

Comment: Just updated it. It's strange that this is happening, it might be best to visit how the JSON is being constructed on the server

Comment: I just looked. it's ugly:

Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(String.Format("{{""success"":[{{""message"":""{0}""}}]}}", "Data Saved")))

Comment: Yeah, looks like it would be best to revise that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80316/discussion-between-metalphoenix-and-anotherdev).

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this

```
var response = JSON.parse(ajaxResponse.responseText);
console.info(response.success[0].message);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just assign to it:

```
var res =  JSON.parse(ajaxResponse.responseText);
ajaxResponse.message = res.success[0].message;
```